# How to integrate Amazon SES with encrypted bucket?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

Is it possible to setup SES to store emails in encrypted bucket?

I created empty bucket during this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-receipt-rule.html

and everything works. I can send an email and it appears in S3 bucket.
If only I add AWS-KMS encryption to the bucket, and edit the same rule-set with the same bucket i'm getting:

```
"Could not write to bucket: test (Request ID: xxx)"
```

When I disable encryption I can save the rule-set again.

I tried adding policies like this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ses.html#services-ses-permissions

or this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-permissions.html#receiving-email-permissions-kms

and nothing.